# Choose a month of a year to rank then give resulting ranks to the rest years

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, rank

Sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                        year=c(2014,2014,2015,2015),
                        month=c(1,2),
                        new.employee=c(4,6,2,6,23,2,5,34))

  id year month new.employee
1  A 2014     1            4
2  A 2014     2            6
3  A 2015     1            2
4  A 2015     2            6
5  B 2014     1           23
6  B 2014     2            2
7  B 2015     1            5
8  B 2015     2           34
```

Desired outcome:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                        year=c(2014,2014,2015,2015),
                        month=c(1,2),
                        new.employee=c(4,6,2,6,23,2,5,34),
                        new.employee.rank=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1))

  id year month new.employee new.employee.rank
1  A 2014     1            4                 1
2  A 2014     2            6                 1
3  A 2015     1            2                 2
4  A 2015     2            6                 2
5  B 2014     1           23                 2
6  B 2014     2            2                 2
7  B 2015     1            5                 1
8  B 2015     2           34                 1
```

The ranking rule is: I choose month 2 in each year to rank number of new employees between A and B. Then I need to give those ranks to month 1. i.e., month 1 of each year rankings must be equal to month 2 ranking in the same year.

I tried these code to get rankings for each month and each year,

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1)
df1[,rank:=rank(new.employee), by=c("year","month")]
```

If (anyone can roll the rank value within a column to replace rank of month 1 by rank of month 2 ), it might be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tried a `data.table` solution, so here's how would I do this using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) # V1.9.6+
temp <- setDT(df1)[month == 2L, .(id, frank(-new.employee)), by = year]
df1[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")]
df1
#    id year month new.employee new.employee.rank
# 1:  A 2014     1            4                 1
# 2:  A 2014     2            6                 1
# 3:  A 2015     1            2                 2
# 4:  A 2015     2            6                 2
# 5:  B 2014     1           23                 2
# 6:  B 2014     2            2                 2
# 7:  B 2015     1            5                 1
# 8:  B 2015     2           34                 1
```

It appears somewhat similar to the above `dplyr` solution. Which is basically ranks the `id`s per year and joins them back to the original data set. I'm using `data.table` V1.9.6+ here.

Comment: nice solution. Could you please briefly explain to me why we neen the "L" after 2, and the "i." before V2, and the last one is the format .(id, ...). sorry, i am a newbie. I am very grateful

Comment: @ David Can you help me to create user-defined function in this case. I am trying to rank many items. I think the function is somewhat like this function(df,item_to_rank). I tried but I could not even return the factor "temp". Could you please help me to nest the successful commands. Thanks a lot

Comment: It worth maybe posting a new question while linking this one when you'll describe exactly what you need. I can't help you based on comments.

Comment: I think I helped you on the new question, but haven't heard from you regarding any feedback.

Comment: Dear David, I am currently reinstall my window so I did not have a chance to check the new post. And I dont know why there was no notification email as for this post. Thanks a lot and I will give feedback asap.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `dplyr`-based solution. The idea is to reduce the data to the parts you want to compare, make the comparison, then join the results back into the original data set, expanding it to fill all of the relevant slots. Note the edits to your code for creating the sample data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                        year=rep(c(2014,2014,2015,2015), 2),
                        month=rep(c(1,2), 4),
                        new.employee=c(4,6,2,6,23,2,5,34))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  # Reduce the data to the slices (months) you want to compare
  filter(month==2) %>%
  # Group the data by year, so the comparisons are within and not across years
  group_by(year) %>%
  # Create a variable that indicates the rankings within years in descending order
  mutate(rank = rank(-new.employee)) %>%
  # To prepare for merging, reduce the new data to just that ranking var plus id and year
  select(id, year, rank) %>%
  # Use left_join to merge the new data (.) with the original df, expanding the
  # new data to fill all rows with id-year matches
  left_join(df1, .) %>%
  # Order the data by id, year, and month to make it easier to review
  arrange(id, year, month)
```

Output:

```
Joining by: c("id", "year")
  id year month new.employee rank
1  A 2014     1            4    1
2  A 2014     2            6    1
3  A 2015     1            2    2
4  A 2015     2            6    2
5  B 2014     1           23    2
6  B 2014     2            2    2
7  B 2015     1            5    1
8  B 2015     2           34    1
```

Comment: Dear ulfelder, it works for my sample but I cannot translate it into my real case as I am a newbie. I cannot understand all of your syntax. However, I am very grateful. I will come back to your suggestion in another day. Now I will use data.table method first.

Comment: In case it helps, I'll add some comments explaining what each step is doing.